# how to find data related to current record only mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want get only current assets record. But it's show me 0 record please help me this what is missing in this query.  How to find only related data not all the assets. I was many try but not success.

Anyone help me this I am very thankful

```
export function assetswisetracking(req, res) {
  return Campaign.find(
    {"assets._Id": req.params.id }, // <= query part
    {assets:{$elemMatch:{"assets._Id": req.params.id}}}  
    )
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}



{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b49d08db8695590d4ea7204"),
    "company_id" : ObjectId("59e07c60bdd6d7a454a89304"),
    "brand_id" : ObjectId("59e090a8bdd6d7a454a89305"),
    "campaign_name" : "testing campaign 1",  
    "no_of_days" : "7",
    "status" : "Executed",
    "updated_date" : ISODate("2018-07-14T10:29:33.164Z"),
    "created_date" : ISODate("2018-07-14T10:29:33.164Z"),
    "active" : true,   
    "assets" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b49cef1b8695590d4ea7203"),         
            "brand_id" : ObjectId("59e090a8bdd6d7a454a89305"),
            "medium" : "Billboard", 
            "quantity" : "1",
            "image" : "1531563759445.JPG",
            "__v" : 0,         
            "assets_planned_end_date" : ISODate("2018-07-14T10:30:13.000Z"),
            "assets_planned_start_date" : ISODate("2018-07-14T10:30:13.000Z"),
            "users_list" : [ 
                ObjectId("5a226aa9c5941e2f845667c3")
            ],
            "outdoor_tracking" : []
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b49cef1b8695590d4ea7203"),         
            "brand_id" : ObjectId("59e090a8bdd6d7a454a89305"),
            "medium" : "Billboard 2",
            "quantity" : "5",
            "image" : "1531562115.JPG",
            "__v" : 0,         
            "assets_planned_end_date" : ISODate("2018-07-14T10:30:13.000Z"),
            "assets_planned_start_date" : ISODate("2018-07-14T10:30:13.000Z"),
            "users_list" : [ 
                ObjectId("5a1d0c63ea1c673058e88d2c")
            ],
            "outdoor_tracking" : []
        },
    ],
    "__v" : 1
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Field is case sensitive, you need to use

```
 {"assets._id": req.params.id }
```

Comment: dude its not a typo , definitely it will help others and i am sure OP is not aware of this. btw downvoting this is absolutely bad

Comment: haha ok! o got the downvote immediately you posted the comment :P